# Partial model to compute activation in Tensorflow2/Keras with Sequential within Sequential

Tags: tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I have a GAN model that is made of :

- *generator*, a keras.models.Sequential
- *discriminator*, a Sequential too
- *combined*, the combination of both previous as a Sequential

```
combined = models.Sequential([generator, discriminator], name='combined')
```

Training works fine, example (https://tonio73.github.io/data-science/generative/MNIST_GAN.html)

Issue is when I want to compute activation maps for a part of this network, that is until layer #n of either the generator of the discriminator.

For a Sequential *model* containing ordinary layers, it is possible to do something like :

`keras.models.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=model.layers[0].output)`

With above architecture, I get some "Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor(...)" error for :

```
keras.models.Model(inputs=combined.layers[0].input, outputs=combined.layers[1].input)
```

While following is fine:

```
keras.models.Model(inputs=combined.layers[0].input, outputs=combined.layers[0].output)

keras.models.Model(inputs=combined.layers[0].layers[0].input, outputs=combined.layers[0].layers[1].input)
```

I am looking for a way to properly access the input and outputs of the second level Sequential models.

Answer (score 0):

Following Tensorflow issue on Github is providing part of the solution:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34977

The right way to access inputs and outputs is through the API *get_input_at(n)*, *get_output_at(n)* in which *n* is the number of levels in between the layers (depth difference to common ancestor).

E.g.:

```
keras.models.Model(inputs=combined.layers[0].get_input_at(0), outputs=combined.layers[1].layers[0].get_input_at(1))
```